# How to handle a function input

Tags: function, input, average, rate

I need to make a program that calculates **the average rate of change of a function.**

And my struggle is how to deal with the **function input**.

I need my program be able to **understand a function** and **replace x per values**.

Example:

Write the function:

input: f(x) = x^3 - 9x

Write the x value:

input: 9

I need the program, to automatic **replace the function values with the x value**, i mean like this:

f(9) = 9^3 - 9x9

I was thinking code this in java, but i have no required language, can be any one.

Answer (score 0):

You've basically answered the question with your pseudo code! I don't know Java, but I'll do my best.

```java
public static void main(float xVariable){
  float answer = Math.pow(xVariable, 3) - (9 * xVariable)
  System.out.println(answer);
}
```

Hopefully that's pretty close!

Comment: Hey, hello! Thank you for your answer, it definitely helped me. Solved the first part of the "problem", and the other half it´s that the "3" and "9" values are not static, the idea is that the user writes the deserved function and the program handle to extract the function values. That adapts to example f(x) = 10^x - 94*x -(-2*x). I mean if exists something to extract and adapt the results.